# Allow l-value references and disallow r-value references as a function parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

So I have a class that manages a resource. Similar to `std::mutex`, it has `acquire` and `release` methods.  To be a good RAII-style programmer, I want to implement the analog to `std::unique_lock`, to prevent the resource from from being acquired forever.  However, for semantic reasons, `acquire` and `release` are `const` functions (trust me on this one).

So that means that my constructor for my RAII class has a signature of `RAIIType( const T &)`.  This problem is, is that an rvalue will bind to this as well. I was hoping to pick SO's brain on a way to disallow this from happening.

In coding terms:

```
class ResourceType
{
public:
   void acquire() const{}
   void release() const{}
};

template< class T >
class RAIIClass
{
public:
   RAIIClass(const T & in_t) : t(in_t) { t.acquire(); }
   ~RAIIClass() { t.release(); }
private:
   const T & t;
};

ResourceType foo() { return ResourceType(); }

int main()
{
   ResourceType x1;
   const ResourceType & x2(x1);

   {
      RAIIClass<ResourceType> x(x1); //Allowable
   }
   {
      RAIIClass<ResourceType> x(x2); //Allowable
   }
   {
      RAIIClass<ResourceType> x(foo()); //Currently allowable, would like to disallow.
   }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid rvalues?

Comment: Also, be aware that with this design, your `RAIIClass` is non-assignable (maybe that's fine, but just beware!).

Comment: Immediate solution: `RAIIClass(T&&) = delete;` But I'm not convinced this isn't an xy-problem.

Comment: @juanchopanza I can't really get into it because proprietary reasons, but they're semantically const, and have a mutable variable on the inside.  You'll have to trust me that it makes sense in the real problem.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth The destructor of RAIIClass would call an invalid ref if the parameter was a temporary

Comment: @dyp I tried that, if I overload the constructor and delete the T&& type, it just calls the first one instead.

Comment: @Hounddog: Ah yeah, that makes sense.  (I'm not saying the whole thing makes sense, but at least wanting to avoid rvalues does!)

Comment: @dyp Well if X is "how to disallow r-values", then Y is "how to I create an RAII class for ResourceType in such a way to make it as idiot-proof as possible?"

Comment: @Hounddog: dyp proposed something like https://ideone.com/Vk5HzU which produces the error you want.

Comment: @dyp ...never mind about your solution not working.  It seems to work in the test problem, but doesn't work in my actual application, so...something unexpected is going on, and warrants investigation.  However, yes, that seems to be a workable solution to the question asked.  Cheers.

Comment: @Jarod42 I can't tag two users in a comment apparently, but see what I just said to dyp :-)

Comment: Oh, I just figured out the problem...the RAII class was being created in a helper function and moved up a scope (in order to hide some of the template messiness from the user, in the same vein of boost::make_optional or std::make_unique).  So I have to overload the helper function as well.  Looks workable, thanks.

Comment: For those asking about the const acquire/release function...in the real problem there's also a non-const acquire function as well, and "acquiring" will give you a const or non-const version of the actual resource.  In this way, it's impossible to access the internal data without "acquiring" it first, and users of this resource class can still get a const version of the resource in a const environment.  So it's semantically const, even if it has to do a mutable thing on the inside.

Comment: Interesting question and well moderated (with comments) !!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this constructor:

```
RAIIClass(const T&&) = delete;
```

This will bind to either const or non-const rvalues, where as both const and non-const lvalues will prefer your existing constructor:

```
RAIIClass(const T & in_t) : t(in_t) { t.acquire(); }
```

Comment: Yup, that was suggested above, but you seem to be the fastest to actually type it up as an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to forbidding the creation of managers for temporaries is to change the manager class to store the managed object internally when invoked with a temporary ([Demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/901eb2921c56065c)):

```
template< class T >
class RAIIClass;
template <typename T>
RAIIClass<T> make_guard(T&&);

template< class T >
class RAIIClass
{
public:
   ~RAIIClass() { t.release(); }

private:
   friend RAIIClass make_guard<>(T&&);
   RAIIClass(T&& in_t) : t(std::forward<T>(in_t)) { t.acquire(); }

   T t;
};

template <typename T>
RAIIClass<T> make_guard(T&& t)  {
   return {std::forward<T>(t)};
}

ResourceType foo() { return {}; }

int main()
{
   ResourceType x1;
   const ResourceType & x2(x1);

   {
      auto x = make_guard(x1); //Allowable
   }
   {
      auto x = make_guard(x2); //Allowable
   }
   {
      auto x = make_guard(foo()); //Allowable too.
   }
}
```

Comment: +1: The trick here is to have a factory deduced function that takes `T&&`, a constructor that takes `T&&`, and you store a `T` in your instance: this is a common pattern.  The `T` is a value-type iff the `T&&` was an rvalue temporary, and otherwise it is a reference-type.  It is probably a good idea to explictly block `operator=` and copy-construct, and explicitly allow move-construct, in `RAIIClass`.